# How to make autoplay with li elements on screen one at a time with setInterval using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

I want to go through li element's that will display the img on the screen one by one by using setInterval. I'm not sure how to approach this, I already made the buttons work to click that will go through the li element's.

I tried making a function that will go through the li element's and then call it inside a setInterval. It didn't work as I expected, it does count from 0-4, and repeats.

```
const slide = document.querySelector("[data-slides]");
console.log(slide);

const newIndex = [...slide.children];
console.log(newIndex);
let start = 0;

function slider() {
  if (start < newIndex.length) {
    start = start + 1;
  } else {
    start = 0;
  }
  console.log(start);
}

setInterval(slider, 2000);
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/jimmyjimenez2400/pen/KKBeezj

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the visibility of the li elements on each iteration of the slider() function. you can add a class ("visible") to the current li element and remove it from the previous one, and track of the current slide index.

kindly try this approach:

```
const slide = document.querySelector("[data-slides]");
const newIndex = [...slide.children];
let start = 0;

function slider() {
  newIndex[start].classList.remove("visible");
  start = (start + 1) % newIndex.length;
  newIndex[start].classList.add("visible");
}

setInterval(slider, 2000);
```

Comment: I can understand most of the code, for example the second line in the function slider, that will make it loop around. I'm not getting how you were able to put currentIndex since it wasn't defined. Can you explain more further?

Comment: I apologize for the mistake, I correct the solution